# Can't find Google Chrome in "Default Programs" in my control panel

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I can't open links from skype and other programs with my Google Chrome, I have it set as default browser throught my preferences in Google Chrome, but when I checked my Default Programs in my control panel I couldn't even find Google Chrome listed!

What can I do to "add" chrome to the list of default programs? It wasnt listed here either "Set Associations" under the HTTP and HTTPS, it just said "Chrome HTML document, Unknown Program".

Comment: get the latest version of chrome and re-install it !!!

Comment: I installed chrome last week (the latest version) and the links haven't been working from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

We have to set it from within Google Chrome to make it the default browser.

In Chrome browser, go to  setting , then click the button that says "make Google Chrome the default Browser for this computer".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Default Program Editor is a great program that can help you set the default programs in Windows. It is portable so no need to install anything. http://defaultprogramseditor.com/